# Docker hub automated build falling with missing variable

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have been set the "BUILD ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" with the necessary variable, and added the `hooks/build` with:

```
#! /bin/bash

docker build \
  --build-arg HBASE_VERSION="${HBASE_VERSION}" \
  -f "${DOCKERFILE_PATH}" \
  -t "${IMAGE_NAME}" .
```

Not are passing in build process, take a look in the log output:

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-1060-aws
Components: [{u'Version': u'18.03.1-ee-3', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'4.4.0-1060-aws', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.37', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'b9a5c95', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.10.2'}}]
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2018-08-30T18:42:30.000000000+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.37
Platform: {u'Name': u''}
Version: 18.03.1-ee-3
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: b9a5c95
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.10.2
Starting build of index.docker.io/rowupper/hbase-base:1.4.9...
Step 1/9 : FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9
---> b76bbdb2809f
Step 2/9 : RUN apk add --no-cache wget bash perl
---> Running in 50cf82a30723
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 130 MiB in 60 packages
Removing intermediate container 50cf82a30723
---> 108b5b9b6569
Step 3/9 : ARG HBASE_VERSION
---> Running in 5407a0bcbf60
Removing intermediate container 5407a0bcbf60
---> ea35e0967933
Step 4/9 : ENV HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase HBASE_CONF_DIR=/etc/hbase PATH=${HBASE_HOME}/bin:$PATH
---> Running in 3a74e814acc8
Removing intermediate container 3a74e814acc8
---> 7a289348ba9b
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR $HBASE_HOME
Removing intermediate container e842d4658bf1
---> a6fede2510ec
Step 6/9 : RUN wget -O - https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/${HBASE_VERSION}/hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz | tar -xz --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions
---> Running in 39b75bc77c5a
--2019-03-19 18:46:05-- https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase//hbase--bin.tar.gz
Resolving archive.apache.org... 163.172.17.199
Connecting to archive.apache.org|163.172.17.199|:443...
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
404 Not Found
2019-03-19 18:46:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
tar: invalid magic
tar: short read
Removing intermediate container 39b75bc77c5a
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -O - https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/${HBASE_VERSION}/hbase-${HBASE_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz | tar -xz --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner --no-same-permissions' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is visible that the variable is missing, what I need do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hooks/build` file need living in the same directory of `Dockerfile`.

My project has several subfolders, each folder with a `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try ARG and ENV, like

```
ARG HBASE_HOME="default_value"
ENV HBASE_HOME="$HBASE_HOME"
```

in your Dockerfile

build-arg VALUE should override the "default_value".